# Double Click Bottom Right of Auto Fill

Tags: excel, vba

seems like an easy question here, but is there a code to simulate the double clicking of bottom right of fill handle?  So I would have 3 cells selected, from column A, B and C; and the autofill should duplicate the values inside down all the blanks in A, B and C till there is no more blank more blanks in C.

[image]

**to this:**

[image]

Comment: Not sure about autofill but I know you can select a range and `.filldown`

Comment: Ahhhh, someone already answered that. And yeah, you're right Samuel!

Comment: Yes, we both submitted at the same time! That answer is probably a bit more elegant than what I would have come up with tho.

Comment: @SamuelEverson haha, regardless, you both know things I don't know of.. So that's equally great! Nice to see you around here as always!

Comment: Hot tip: [Documentation is your friend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/visual-basic-conceptual-topics). It doesn't hurt to [look for things in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/excel/object-model) even if you don't know what it is you are looking for. For example, here I would have gone to the `Range` object and looked at properties/methods to see if anything looks like it would fit. Most likely I'd have seen `.FillDown` method and gone from there.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the tip mate!!

Comment: @SamuelEverson I actually kinda found the solution and considered deleting this post because I felt stupid haha. But someone answered before I could do that... Thanks though!

Comment: Rather than delete a post its more beneficial to the community to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Remember, there are *a lot* of users on SO and you're likely not the first nor last person to ask your question.

Comment: @SamuelEverson Definitely! I'm relatively new to both SO and VBA macro, so i'm trying my best to pick up both SO's posting questions etiquette and also learning as much as possible for VBA. The community has been great too! Thanks for the tip and guidance this far :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub FillDown()
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown))
    Set rng = rng.Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1, rng.Columns.Count)

    rng.FillDown
End Sub
```

Comment: By far the simplest answer i've seen.