# For every blank cell in column, run an auto fill macro

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

**To this:**

[image]

I would like the set of code to be able to pick up every blank in column C and perform a macro in it. It would have been easy if my sheet has a fixed range, however, my list is constantly increasing in rows... Hence, I would need the macro to be able to run macro on blank cells and skip on those filled cells. **The macro should also end upon the last filled cell in the column**.

```
 Sub Testing()

Dim Rl As Long                      ' last row
Dim Tmp As Variant
Dim R As Long                       ' row counter

With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet       ' modify to suit
    Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    ' work on column C
    For R = 1 To Rl                 ' start the loop in row 1
        Tmp = .Cells(R, "C").Value
        If Len(Tmp) Then
            Cells(R, "C").Select
            Call AutoFill
        End If
    Next R
End With


Sub AutoFill()
Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown))
    Set rng = rng.Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1, rng.Columns.Count)
    rng.FillDown

End Sub
```

Comment: I know I've been asking quite a few questions today, but this will be the last one for me tonight (i live in singapore), so sorry for those that have been reading my many questions repeatedly today.

Comment: What is `AutoFill`? (Pretty sure it's from your last question, but how did you implement it to your project?) Also what exactly is the problem, any errors or just not getting the expected result?

Comment: Asking a lot of questions is not something to appologize for @JoshNg. It's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here: `If Len(Tmp) Then` and that's just checking if `Tmp` has any length. So this actually ignores your empty cells by skipping them. Instead you are selecting cells with values in them.

Do not loop all cells in a range. Instead just look at those empty cells of interest. For example:

```
Sub Testing()

Dim LR As Long, LC as Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
With ws
    LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LC = .Cells(LR, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LR, LC))
    If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(rng) > 0 Then
        For Each area In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Areas
            area.Offset(-1).Resize(area.Rows.Count + 1).FillDown
        Next
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

As you can see I left out `.Select` and `ActiveSheet` as that's poor coding and usually not needed at all.

Comment: I believe `AutoFill` is [doing this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61425881/9663006).

Comment: Right, if so, then we don't even need to loop all empty cells. Something much easier can be applied called areas....@SamuelEverson. I haven't inspected what `AutoFill` would imply... thanks

Comment: Hi both! So basically I have an autofill macro that would move a cell up and perform autofill down to the blanks. However, due to my list being ever growing... I kinda need a macro that would perform only Autofill for all blank cells; however, it should always stop at the last filled cell (which in this case is **break**).

Comment: I wasn't familiar with the `.Areas` property/object. Good to know!

Comment: Oh my god, this is it. Thank you so much @JvdV. Of course, samuel everson!! You guys were great, helped me in my current project so much :))

Comment: @JvdV oh yes, one last question, with your codes, how do I get it to only start from row 4?

Comment: @JoshNg, see this line: `Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LR, LC))`? Change the row parameter of the starting cell of the range, meaning: `Set rng = .Range(.Cells(4, 1), .Cells(LR, LC))` will do.

Comment: Great! I will leave it as it is now. Thank you!