# Using the FillUp function

Tags: excel, vba

In a spreadsheet I have, I am attempting to apply the FillUp function to column I (Type) without overwriting ABC. Is there a way I can use this within VBA?

If anyone has any advise it would be greatly appreciated!!

[image: Test data for applying the FillUp function in VBA]

Comment: You can't fill the whole column if there are cells already with data and you don't want to overwrite, not at once. You either loop through each Cell and check if its value is null and then give it a value, or loop using the autofill.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61426926/9758194) is almost exactly what you are after (just rework it to `FillUp`. Loop through `Areas` and play around with `Offset` and `Resize`. It won't be too hard =)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below code :

```
Sub macro1()

Dim lastrow, firstrow As Long
lastrow = Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
firstrow = 2

While firstrow <= lastrow
    Range("I" & firstrow).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.FillUp
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    firstrow = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Row
Wend


End Sub
```